# when calling startActivityForResult funtion from the unity c# giving non-static method NOT FOUND, BUT working for startActivity funtion

Tags: java, c#, unity-game-engine

this function for calling **startActivity** and **startActivityForResult** from unity(c#) side.

```
        public bool openUrl(string packageName, string url)
        {
            
#if UNITY_ANDROID
            AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
            AndroidJavaObject unityActivity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
            AndroidJavaObject pManager = unityActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getPackageManager");

            //For accessing static strings(ACTION_VIEW) from android.content.Intent
            AndroidJavaClass intentStaticClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.content.Intent");
            string actionView = intentStaticClass.GetStatic<string>("ACTION_VIEW");

            //Create Uri
            AndroidJavaClass uriClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.net.Uri");
            AndroidJavaObject uriObject = uriClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("parse", url);

            //Psss ACTION_VIEW and Uri.parse to the intent
            AndroidJavaObject intent = new AndroidJavaObject("android.content.Intent", actionView, uriObject);

            try
            {
                if (pManager.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getPackageInfo", packageName, 0) != null)
                {
                    intent.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setPackage", packageName);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.LogWarning("Failed to Open App 1: " + e.Message);
                return false;
            }

            try
            {
               //unityActivity.Call("startActivity", intent);        // this is working
                unityActivity.Call("startActivityForResult", intent);  // BUT this is not working
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.LogWarning("Failed to Open App 2: " + e.Message);
                //Open with Browser
                string link = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + packageName + "&hl=en";

                Application.OpenURL(link);
                return false;
            }

#endif
            return false;
        }
```

and code below is in my UnityPlayerActivity.java

```
@Override public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            switch (resultCode) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    //do something
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    //do something
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Payment Canceled by user.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                    mUnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("Canvas_Pay_Notification", "CallFromAndroidOverride", "true");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

[SCREENSHOT for showing startActivityForResult NOT FOUND](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYyTF.jpg)

I wanted, when user press back on overlay opened, then condition of Activity.RESULT_CANCELED should run, in onActivityResult() in the UnityPlayerActivity.java

Comment: Please do not show us screenshots of errors, but post the errors directly as text.
Also, please create a minimal reproducible example and be more clear about what happens and what you expect to happen.